# Cordova Network Information Plugin: broken?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

This is a page where I am attempting to load a backup from the file system if the device cannot connect

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/about.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <ons-screen>
        <ons-navigator title = "About">
            <ons-page id="page" font-align="center">

            </ons-page>
        </ons-navigator>
    </ons-screen>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var page = document.getElementById("page");

        if(navigator.connection.type != Connection.NONE){
            page.innerHTML='<iframe src="http://www.website.com/about/" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>';
        }else{
            page.innerHTML='<iframe src="aboutBackup.html" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>';
        }
</script>
</html>
```

I installed the plugin using the github instructions (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md)

I can't figure out why, but I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined on line 22 where I check the connection type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add cordova.js in your file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Then listen to device ready function and shot for the GOAL

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady()
{

    if(navigator.connection.type=='none')
    {
         alert("Wait I'm offline.");
    }
    else
    {
          page.innerHTML='<iframe src="aboutBackup.html" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>';
    }
}
</script>
```

Anything you do have to be after device ready function is fired. And without cordova.js cordova plugins won't work.

Comment: I think this should work, but it's not.  I have a cordova.js in my www/ directory and I don't believe I should have that there.  I ran it in browser and checked the console and it is giving errors like "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"  I am going to try moving that file out of the project.

Comment: moving it just gave a file not found exception

Comment: Browser can't work with cordova.js, you need to run the project in a emulator or device. @deavisdude

Comment: The reason I ran it in browser was because on my android device and ios emulator, nothing happens on the page and I don't know where to see any errors.

Comment: Give a alert inside device ready, and see if that show after app is loaded in device or emulator. It should work if other things are right. And to view errors from android you can open eclipse logcat while your android device is connected with computer, and then install with CLI. Then you can check for the errors. Can't tell about the ios. Oh! and I used this system to view errors with windows, can't tell if this will work on mac @deavisdude

Comment: Ok, so I used LogCat in Eclipse and noticed this from index.html, don't know if it's relevant "06-20 11:15:20.916: D/CordovaLog(4353): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 53 : Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined
06-20 11:15:20.916: E/Web Console(4353): Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined:53"

Comment: I also noticed that it logged my network type correctly, but the page wasn't loaded either way.

Comment: Oh! and no alerts, but I've never seen the alerts work on mobile, pretty sure you need a plugin.

Comment: There is a error in your index.html file. Line number 53. Check it.

Comment: Right, that's app.initialize();

Comment: alert works on mobile, phonegap is a web tech :) Alert works, no plugin needed.

Comment: Still nothing loads on the about page.  I did get these (they were there before, but after the app error:  06-20 11:26:29.739: D/WebKit(8481): ERROR: 
06-20 11:26:29.739: D/WebKit(8481): WebKit does not yet implement getComputedStyle for '-webkit-overflow-scrolling'.
06-20 11:26:29.739: D/WebKit(8481): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/css/CSSComputedStyleDeclaration.cpp(935) : void WebCore::logUnimplementedPropertyID(int)

Comment: 06-20 11:26:32.031: E/ViewRootImpl(8481): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
this was red so I'm assuming it's an error

Comment: Opps! I'm sorry bro, I give up. Can't tell about this error. I don't think it has anything to do with the network plugin.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using iScroll somewhere else, but this should work even if that is totally broken